# Обмануть таймер сайта чтобы работал деморежим

Tags: javascript, angularjs

На сайте `https://scoutdata.feedconstruct.com/` при просмотре лайва открывается отдельное окно для просмотра демо режима матча на 2 минуты.

Подскажите, как обнулить или удалить таймер, чтобы демо-режим не останавливался при окончании таймера.

Код прикрепляю:

[image: скриншот девтулов]

Comment: А где код, собственно говоря?

Comment: @ΝNL993, на скриншоте девтулов - он с разметкой вопроса накосячил.

Comment: Впрочем, до ангулярных свойств я докапываться не умею нормально. Вот если бы реакт... Но скриншота в любом случае недостаточно.

Comment: Что выдаёт `angular.version` в консоли?

Comment: @ΝNL993, я неожиданно понял, что это первый ангуляр, а не второй)

Comment: Я так понимаю, эта страница доступна только после регистрации?

Comment: @ΝNL993, посмотри под ответом комментарий насчёт твоей правки.

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуй выполнить в консоли

   ```
   angular.element(".trialTime").scope().trialTimer
   ```

   Предположу, что ты увидишь время в секундах.
2. Выведи и разверни

   ```
   angular.element(".trialTime").scope()
   ```

   Стоит убедиться, что `trialTimer` находится именно в нём, а не в одном из прототипов. Если в нём нет, поднимайся по `$parent` пока не найдёшь, где есть.
3. Чтобы сбросить таймер попробуй выполнить

   ```
   angular.element(".trialTime").scope()/*.$parent*/.$apply("trialTimer=90")
   ```

   Тут `.$parent` надо вставить и повторить столько раз, сколько пришлось до него подниматься.
4. Если это сработало, заверни в интервал:

   ```
   setInterval(() => {
     angular.element(".trialTime").scope()/*.$parent*/.$apply("trialTimer=90")
   }, 60000)
   ```

Если что-то пошло не по плану, нужны соответствующие сведения.
<s>А ещё лучше, ты бы сайт назвал.</s> Регистрироваться не буду.

Comment: @ΝNL993, что касается [правки](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/715857) ответа: `setTimeout` вместо `setInterval` - это действительно моя ошибка, впрочем, имело смысл править сразу в 4м пункте. Что касается форматирования блоков кода, то ты накосячил: у меня был отступ 8 пробелов, потому 4 оставляют код внутри списка и ещё 4 делают непосредственно блок кода. При переформатировании на три бэктика надо было оставлять отступ в 4 пробела чтобы код остался внутри списка. Что касается языка, то указывать его явно не требуется, т. к. он уже прописан дефаултным для метки [tag:javascript].

Comment: Да и вообще, при ошибках в логике кода лучше сначала в комментарии об этом писать, чтобы автор мог поправить сам.

Comment: Ладно, буду знать в будущем, спасибо.